# Não consigo mostrar dados com o vue js

Tags: vue.js

Não consigo mostrar dados com o vue js, no meu html tenho:

```
<div class="panel">
     <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="col-md-3"><img src="../images/aeracao/produto.png" alt=""></div>
         <div class="col-md-9"><b>{{ response.views[1].produto }}</b><br>
          <span class="st-label-info">Produto</span></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

E o código do vue:

```
var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#aeracaoApp',
        data: {
            response: [],
            currentGrupoArco: 1,
            mensagem: '',
            showModal: false,
            historico: []
        },
        methods : {
            update: function () {
                this.$http.get(URL_ALL).then((response) => {
                    this.response = response.data;
                }, (response) => {
                     //console.log('erro')
                });
            },
```

...

Tentei mostrar tbm apenas a váriavel {{ response }} e dai mostra:

```
{"views":{"1":{"aeracao_id":129,"motor_id":1,"motor_ligado":true,"seq_motor_cont":1,"produto":"Teste"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

O `vue` tem um método nativo chamado `update`, por isso não deves usar um método teu chamado `update`.

Antes desse ajax chegar tens de ter um método de render seguro. Ou seja quando o `response` ainda está vazio. No `data` sugiro teres `{}` pois é o que vais receber, e não `[]`.

Depois podes fazer assim:

```js
const futureResponse = {
  views: {
    '1': {
      aeracao_id: 129,
      motor_id: 1,
      motor_ligado: true,
      seq_motor_cont: 1,
      produto: 'Teste'
    }
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#aeracaoApp',
  data() {
    return {
      response: {},
      currentGrupoArco: 1,
      mensagem: '',
      showModal: false,
      historico: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData: function() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.response = futureResponse;
      }, 1500);
    },
    getProp(key) {
      return this.response.views && this.response.views[1] && this.response.views[1][key];
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getData();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="aeracaoApp">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-md-3"><img src="../images/aeracao/produto.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-md-9"><b>{{ getProp('produto') }}</b><br>
        <span class="st-label-info">Produto</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

O mais correto seria voce utilizar o mounted nesse caso

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#aeracaoApp',
data: {
    response: [],
    currentGrupoArco: 1,
    mensagem: '',
    showModal: false,
    historico: []
},
methods : {
    update: function () {
        this.$http.get(URL_ALL).then((response) => {
            this.response = response.data;
        }, (response) => {
             //console.log('erro')
        });
    },
},
mounted() {
    this.update();
}
```

});